# jhipster quick start application

Tags: jhipster

I tried the quick start application -> http://www.jhipster.tech/creating-an-app/

I selected a monolith application and finally a war was successfully generated.

Since this is a spring boot app , how can I get the jar file ? In our production server we have only java installed ( no gradle) and hence would want to run the java -jar command to launch the application

Also when i try accessing the application from http://localhost:8080 , I get a  blank page with no errors on the console .

From where can I view the errors ?

Comment: Please read the docs http://www.jhipster.tech/development/#working-with-angular and http://www.jhipster.tech/production/

Comment: Thanks for pointing out to the right sections in the documentation